# How can i check for an existence of duplicate value in mysql using perl and through an error message on the same page?

Tags: html, mysql, perl, dbi

```
use CGI;
use strict;
use DBI();
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

print "content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
my $q     = new CGI;
my $name  = $q->param('name');
my $email = $q->param('email');

print $q->header;
#connect to database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost","root",
                       "mukesh", {'RaiseError' => 1});

eval { $dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp (name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL)") };
print "creating table emp failed: $@" if $@;
print "<br>";
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO emp(name,email) values('$name','$email')");

my $sql = qq/select * from emp order by name/; 
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Can't prepare $sql:$dbh->errstrn";
my $rv  = $sth->execute() or die "can't execute the query: $sth->errstrn";
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print join(", ",@row),"<br>";
}
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

print "<br>Total no of records : $rv";
if ($rv>=1){
    print "<br>Record has been successfully updated !!!<br>";
} else {
    print "<br>Error!!while inserting record<br>";
    exit;
}
```

When I submit the html form for the same value of email address i am redirected to another
page with the following error:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Software error:

DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry 'rajesh@gmail.com' for key 'email' at C:/Apache2/cgi-bin/connectivity.cgi line 27.
```

1) I dont want this error to be displayed,instead i want to display my own message if email address already exists.something like **"email id already exists please enter a new id"**

2) after the above problem is solved, i want it to be displayed on the same page where
i am submitting the form.

this line seems to be failing for duplicate entry

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO emp(name,email) values('$name','$email')");
```

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: nothing ... i will remove that

Comment: Well, how about another query that tests if the email is already present? Only if that doesn't return anything you could insert a new one. You could probably do that in one query, I think. Oh, and you have a potential SQL injection problem. Use placeholders instead of interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said you can test to see if the email already exists but what happens if someone submits your form and it gets to the insert after another copy of your code has already tested the email does not exist. It would be better to simply catch this condition by wrapping your insert in an eval (as you already have RaiseError enabled) and testing err and state afterwards to see if the error was a duplicate entry.

```
eval {
  $dbh->do("INSERT INTO emp(name,email) values(?,?)", undef, $name, $email);
};
if ($@) {
  # you might want to use state instead of err but you did not show us the state
  if ($dbh->err =~ /Duplicate entry/) {
    # already registered
  } else {
    # report what is in $@ - it is a different error
  }
}
```

BTW, as you have RaiseError enabled you do not need to keep checking the returns (your "or die") from various DBI methods - they will die automatically if they fail and as PrintError defaults to 1, as you have found they will print the error.

One last thing, the fat comma (=>) automatically stringifies the thing to the left so "{'RaiseError' => 1}" can be written "{RaiseError => 1}".

Comment: Thanks for ponting out the problem.I didn't think about this

Answer (score 3):

To handle this you could check if the email address already exists.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE email = ?");
$sth->execute($email);
my $rows = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref();
$sth->finish();

if ($rows->[0] == 0) {
    # Insert your email address
} else {
    # Show an error message
}
```

And as amon pointed out you should always use Placeholders for your statements.